# Turn on/off click functionality using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have 2 flag image links, German and English. When the user clicks German flag I want to disable `onclick` for German.  And if user clicks English, then I want to re-enable `onclick` for German again.

I'm using this, but it's not working:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

$('a#German').click(function() {
   $(this).removeAttr('onclick').unbind('click');
 });

 $('a#English').click(function() {
    $('a#German').attr('onclick').bind('click');
 });

});
```

Comment: Note: when you use an id selector, do not prefix it with a element selector... `#German` instead of `a#German`

Comment: why are you using inlined click handlers?

Comment: Your `bind` call is missing the second argument, the event handler function. Also, you should use `on` and `off`, as `bind` and `unbind` are obsolete.

Comment: unbinding a click handler on an `a` element seems like it wouldn't work

Comment: Hi Arun, that's the way this code works so far, haven't tried anything else.

Comment: @RobMyrick Put `@` before the screen name if you want him to be notified of your answer.

Comment: @Barmar, would you be so kind to put this function into your `.on` and `.off` functions as an example?

Comment: Unless you're doing event delegation, the arguments to `on` and `off` are the same as for `bind` and `unbind`.

Comment: @Barmar, thank you....I still will need an answer if possible though.  thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with farmerjoe's?

Comment: I'm trying it now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of switching all those handlers and driving yourself nuts I'd try this approach:

```
<a href="#lang-1" class="language-choice language-choice-selected" data-lang="lang-1">Lang 1</a>
<a href="#lang-2" class="language-choice" data-lang="lang-2">Lang 2</a>
<a href="#lang-3" class="language-choice" data-lang="lang-3">Lang 3</a>
```

Then, in my Javascript, I'd do:

```
var $languageChoices = $('.language-choice');

$languageChoices.on('click', function(){
  var $link = $(this);
  if( ! $link.is('.language-choice-selected')){
    var language = $link.data('lang');
    $languageChoices.removeClass('language-choice-selected');
    $link.addClass('language-choice-selected');
    switchLanguageTo(language); // I guess?
  }

});
```

This way you just don't do anything if you select the current language.

Answer (score 1):

Just to simplify farmerjoe's a bit, you can delegate the click event to the first common parent of the flag buttons, and use a class to toggle their active staus, like so:

```
var buttons = $("#german, #english");
var parent = $("#parent");  // or whatever the common parent is

parent.on("click", "#german, #english", function() {
    buttons.toggleClass("active");
}

parent.on("click", "#german.active", german_handler );
parent.on("click", "#english.active", english_handler );
```

Note that you'll need to start one of the buttons with the `active` class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the handler known, something like this:

The way this works is, the window is loaded and the command `jQuery(document).ready(function() {//code})` then calls the function that is given as its argument.  That function when run, will find the elements, in this case your english and german buttons, and give them some protocol for when a `click` event takes place.  This is what the `bind("event",my_named_handler)` function does.  The arguments are the `"event"` which describes the type of event you are waiting for, and the handler is a function which will *handle* the event.  If you assign this as `bind("click",function(){//code})` the function remains anonymous and cannot be referenced.  When you call `unbind("click",my_named_handler)` your code will look for handlers that have been linked to your element and remove them.  If you have gone about the way of using an anonymous function then you will not be able to reference by any easy method.  By defining your handler in a variable you can pass the same handler to both `bind` and `undbind`, making the link and unlink take place as the function knows exactly what handler you are referencing in both cases.

The `bind("event",handler)` is a function which links an element to a listener for an event, and

```
var german_handler = function() {
     // do german clicky stuff

};
var english_handler = function() {
     // do english clicky stuff
};

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#German').bind("click",german_handler);
    $('#German').bind("click",function() {
        $('#German').unbind("click",german_handler);
    });
    $('#English').bind("click",english_handler);
    $('#English').bind("click",function() {
        $('#German').bind("click",german_handler);
    });
});
```

Also, it is better to use `#German` instead of `a#German`, `id` tags should usually be unique.

Comment: forgive me for being in-experienced.  In your code I thought I was actually "doing clicky stuff" inside of `jquery(document).ready(function()`.  Why do I do clicky stuff in outside functions?

Comment: actually, I don't understand.  Sorry.  Can you tell me why stuff is done in outside functions?

Comment: @RobMyrick you set up functions containing the logic you would like to execute whenever a click event happens.  The `jquery(document).ready()` is code that executes when the docuement has loaded, `$('#id').bind()` then defines certain behavior to bind to elements, you set up listeners for these events with behavior for when they are heard.

Comment: So do I need to put this in `var german_handler` at very top of your example?  `$('#German').unbind("click");`.  That is the action I want to take when German is clicked.  Is that right?

Comment: @RobMyrick you could just as well add that call there, but you need to reference the `handler` which you would like to `unbind`.  The `bind()` function links a function to an event, so the purpose of the `unbind()` call is to disestablish this linkage. This is why it needs the format `("#id").bind("event",handler)` and then `("#id").unbind("event",handler)`, they need to reference the same function.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I don't understand how to do it when you mention in those terms.  I'm so sorry.  I just need to see the full code I guess.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't comprehend by text explanation.  the issue is that I don't know what goes here: `//Do english clicky stuff` or `//Do german clicky stuff`.  I'm sorry friend.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39959/discussion-between-rob-myrick-and-farmerjoe)